# asp core tag helper output href is always blank

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to do this:

`<a asp-page="@c.Link.AspPage" asp-all-route-data="routeData">`

*I.e.,* construct a URL from a page name and parameter values that are supplied by the controller.

However, whatever I try the `href` always comes out blank.

I've tried absolute and relativeURLs, absolute and relative project paths, and with and without the `asp-all-route-data` and every time: empty `href`.

How is this supposed to work? I can't work it out.

Comment: Usually if the page does not exist, you will get empty href. Just make sure that @c.Link.AspPage page exists, otherwise provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#changes-to-link-generation):

> Generating a URI for an invalid route (a controller/action or page
>   that doesn't exist) will produce an empty string under endpoint
>   routing instead of producing an invalid URI.

That means if the `@c.Link.AspPage` value is not a existing page, the herf will become empty. I suggest you could re-check the  `@c.Link.AspPage` value to make sure the value is right as below format.

`/Thepagename`

The asp-page attribute is used with Razor Pages. Use it to set an anchor tag's href attribute value to a specific page. Prefixing the page name with a forward slash ("/") creates the URL.

Comment: It definitely is the name of a page. But what exactly is it *supposed* to be: the relative URL to the target page, the path from root beginning with a slash? Or what? I swear I've tried all possibilities.

And what about parameters?

Is there something you have to do in `Startup.cs`? That's something else that isn't explained adequately. I've notice that using `asp-area` makes everything go blank even though I have areas.

Comment: The page is `@page "{ReportId:int}/{SicCode:alpha?}"`

This works: `<a asp-page="/ReportSics" asp-route-ReportId="3">rs1</a>`

This does not: `<a asp-page="/ReportSics" asp-route-ReportId="3" asp-route-SicCode="10">rss2</a>`